# Can we change state before making an API call which uses that state? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

```
 useEffect(() => {
    resetState();
    if (page === 'ADMISSION') {
      fetchAdmissionKitPosts();
    } else if (page === 'WEEKLY') {
      fetchWeeklyKitPosts();
    } else if (page === 'FESTIVAL') {
      fetchFestivalKitPosts();
    }
  }, [page]);
```

So I want to make different API calls based on the page variable. I have to reset the state before making those calls. But while making the call I'm getting the previous state. I came to know that the setState in react is async in nature, so I assume that that's why I'm getting the previous state in the API call functions.

So my question is, how can I make it so that these API calls only run after the state has been reset?

I know that I can use a callback function in the class-based component with the setState function. But I want to keep this component functional.

Comment: Try making `resetState` function asynchronous, and use `await` when calling the function.

Comment: I tried that but it isn't working. Though the setState functions in react are async, await doesn't work with them as they are handled by react.
```
const resetState = async () => {
    await setMarketingPosts([]);
    await setNextPageToken('');
  };
```
```
 useEffect(() => {
    (async function() {
      await resetState();
      fetchData();
    })();
  }, [page]);
```
This is what I tried.

Comment: use callback in setState like setState(()=>) to deal with asynchronous operation. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: @Jerry, I'm not using class-based component

Comment: @Duoro hey what i mean is you can replace setState to setPosts or setPages whatever. read the technical docs carefully and you can find your answers there sometimes

Answer (score 0):

You can implement **setState** callback in functional component with **useEffect**.
if i'm getting it right, you are using two state variables **page** and **posts**, if this is the case you should use two **useEffect** methods like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
   if(page !== ''){
    setMarketingPosts([])
   } 
  }, [page]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (page === 'ADMISSION') {
      fetchAdmissionKitPosts();
    } else if (page === 'WEEKLY') {
      fetchWeeklyKitPosts();
    } else if (page === 'FESTIVAL') {
      fetchFestivalKitPosts();
    }
    setNextPageToken('')
  }, [post]);
```